# Delegate for airplay popover

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to know when the popover on ipad of the mirroring list will be displayed or dismissed. This list is displayed by pressing the airplay button of a MPVolumeView and I am able to know when an item is selected of this list by checking the current route or by adding a notification, but when nothing is selected I want to perform an action. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at my [project on GitHub](https://github.com/alobi/ALMoviePlayerController) that attempts to do this.

https://github.com/alobi/ALMoviePlayerController